# Table width not updated when I hide native scroller of div

Tags: html, css

I need some tricky layout for my project.In this layout i have container div and a table with 100% width. I want to hide the vertical scroller of div element, but content of this div can be scrollable by mouse wheel. For this i have added style to hide the native scroll bar. It works fine when table width was greater than equal to container width. If the table with less than it container, table was not stretched properly with container div. I have assigned 100% width to table but table render to full div.

```css
.content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 17px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    <table style='width: 100%; border-collapse: collpase; table-layout: fixed;'>
      <colgroup>
        <col style='width: 50px;'>
        <col style='width: 50px;'>
        <col style='width: 50px;'>
        <col style='width: 50px;'>
        <col style='width: 50px;'>
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `<table>`

The code provided in question has a typo:

`<table style='width:100%;border-collapse:` **collpase**`;table-layout: fixed;'  >`

thereby rendering the `<table>` to the default style:

`border-collapse: separate;`

---

### Table 1 & Table 2

**Demo 1** has two `<table>s`:

#### Table 1

- with `border-collapse: collapse`
- changed `.content1 {width:105%;...}`
- changed `.container1 {width:250px;...}`

#### Table 2

- with `border-collapse: separate` or default
- changed `<table style="width:105%;...">`
- changed `.container2 {width:262px;...}`

The widths for `.container1` and `.container2` were changed to fixed widths in order to be consistent with the fixed widths of the columns (each at `width:50px`).

---

### Table 3 & Table 4

**Demo 2** has two `<table>s`:

#### Table 3

- with `border-collapse: collapse`
- changed `.contentA {width:calc(100% + 17px;...}`
- changed `.containerA {width:calc(70% + 17px;...}`

#### Table 4

- with `border-collapse: separate` or default
- changed `.contentA {width:calc(100% + 17px;...}`
- changed `.containerA {width:calc(70% + 17px;...}`

These `<table>s` are dynamic in width, using [`calc()` css function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) it compensates for the fixed width of the scrollbar while maintaining relative width percentages.

---

### Demo 1

**Fixed Widths**

```css
.content1 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 17px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 80px;
  /* Changed */
  width: 105%;
}

.content2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container1 {
  /* Changed */
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container2 {
  /* Changed */
  width: 262px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class='container1'>
  <div class='content1'>
    <table style='width:100%;border-collapse: collapse;table-layout: fixed;'>
      <caption>Table 1</caption>
      <colgroup>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class='container2'>
  <div class='content2'>
    <!--Changed width-->
    <table style='width:105%; table-layout: fixed;'>
      <caption>Table 2</caption>
      <colgroup>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
        <col style='width:50px;'>
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Demo 2

**Dynamic Widths**

```css
.contentA {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 17px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 80px;
  width: calc(100% + 17px);
}

.containerA {
  width: calc(70% + 17px);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class='containerA'>
  <div class='contentA'>
    <table style='width:100%;border-collapse: collapse;table-layout: fixed;'>
      <caption>Table 3</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class='containerA'>
  <div class='contentA'>
    <table style='width:100%;table-layout: fixed;'>
      <caption>Table 4</caption>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `padding-right: 17px;` from `content`

If you do not want scroll use `hight:100%` and remove `overflow-y: scroll;`

```css
.content { 
box-sizing: content-box;
border: 1px solid grey;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid grey; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='content'>
<table style='width:100%;border-collapse: collpase;table-layout: fixed;'  >
<colgroup>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
</colgroup>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove this, vertical scroller will appear, i want to hide this also. The table should be scollable on x and y directions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for hiding scrollbar

```
.content::-webkit-scrollbar, .content::-moz-scrollbar, .content::-ms-scrollbar  {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you used padding-right:17px, your table's parent width is more than 100%.So, you table width should be the same width like it's parent width.
Solution::

```
.table{
    width:calc(100% + 16px);
}
```

```css
.content { 
overflow-y: scroll;
padding-right: 17px;
box-sizing: content-box;
border: 1px solid grey;
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid grey; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='content'>
<table style=' width:calc(100% + 16px);border-collapse: collpase;table-layout: fixed;'  >
<colgroup>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
  <col style='width:50px;'>
</colgroup>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to mix things up you can find ways to render html elements dynamically using javascript !